# Sending large arrays of parameters to a GPU shader

Tags: 3d, shader, gpu

I'm interested to map geometry along the path of a spline... e.g take each vertex's `z` value as the distance along the spline and get local XY axes at that point on the spline.

The spline is built of many sections each described by cubic equations for x/y/z e.g x(t) = at^3 + bt^2 + ct + d, so each section can be nicely defined by a matrix or a few float4 values.

But since a spline could easily have 100 sections, that's implying an array of 400-1000 float4 values for the shader to work from. As a novice GPU programmer this leads to a few questions:

1. What's the likely performance hit of setting an array of this size for a mesh which is to be rendered? Negligible or serious?
2. What are the limits on array sizes, and how to they vary across GPUs currently found in the real world? What are the specific names of terms I should be looking at to find this out for a given GPU?

General tips on working with this kind of approach are also welcome since I don't exactly know what I *should* be asking!

It is a vertex-shader I would be looking into here, and I have a requirement to run on pretty bad GPUs, such as iPad2 and DirectX10-supporting integrated graphics chipsets.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, mapping geometry onto a spline at the vertex shader level is not entirely trivial computation-wise (and conceptually). Transform feedback (which is supported on DX10 hardware) is probably something you will want to look into. That way you need not do the calculations every frame for every vertex, only when the spline is modified.

It also depends a bit on what exactly you want. For example, if you want to *place* objects on the spline, but not *warp* the objects themselves, it may be a valid option to evaluate only the origin of every object in a first pass (transform feedback again) and use that as input to transform all vertices later. Maybe using an instance id, or maybe using a separate vertex attribute to index into that data.

**Ad 1:**
The overhead of setting *one* uniform is (more or less) the same as the overhead of setting a thousand uniforms. The pipeline stall and the DMA latency are the dominating factors, and they occur as soon as you touch a single value.
What you want is as few state changes (no matter how "big") between draw calls as possible.

**Ad 2:**
D3D10 mandates at least 4096 vectors of four 32 bit values per constant buffer, of which you can have 14 at the same time.
OpenGL 3.0 (which is the "roughly DX10 class cards" version) is, as usual, a bit mellow in its wording and more relaxed towards the minimum values. A mimimum of 36 bindings of at least 16384 machine words must be supported, of which at least 1024 4-tuples must be available in a vertex shader [[1]](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGet.xml).
Realistically, you can expect *"enough"* (I've never seen anything lower than 65536 being reported).

Also, a D3D10 compatible card, no matter how bad [must support both 16 and 32 bit 4-component floating point textures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc627090) in hardware. The minimum allowable maximum texture size is [8192](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476876#Overview).
Similarly, OpenGL 3.0 mandates 16 and 32 bit vertex and pixel data / textures and requires at least a supported texture size of 1024 (though I've never seen anythng less than 8192).

This means, if uniforms/constants turn out to be not an option, you can alternatively read your spline data from a texture. For a single spline, that could for example be a 1x1024 texture, but the nice thing is: if you have for example 20 splines, you can have them all in one texture (each one in a line) and just change the texture coordinate so you sample a different line. This can possibly eliminate pipeline stalls alltogether.
Further, OpenGL 3.1 introduced Texture Buffer Objects, which are 1-dimensional textures especially for this purpose. The minimum allowable maximum size is 65536, real values are *much higher* (my card reports 134217728).
I'm not enough of an expert on D3D, but pretty much any D3D10 compatible card with recent drivers supports OpenGL 3.1, so since the hardware supports it, it's quite sure that D3D has a similar (slightly differently named) feature.

Comment: It's specifically to warp - conceptually to make a 'curvey' coordinate system. When you say about it being a performance issue, I guess you're right but surely it's comparable with doing bone-weighted skinning/animation, which would be the other way of achieving this?

Comment: So basically what you want is a kind of lattice space deformation with the lattice being interpolated by a spline. The performance problem I see in general with a 1000+ control point spline is that you first have to find the closest pair of control points relative to some coordinate (for every vertex!!!) and then the t value, and some other "minor things" like a point's distance to the spline. This is... um... not quite trivial. Not saying that it isn't possible, but doing such a thing in the vertex shader (i.e. a few hundred thousand times per frame) is... woah, tough stuff. :)

Comment: That said, I really recommend trying an approximation, evaluating the spline at some (whatever) intervals in a separate pass beforehand, using transform feedback (or render to texture, or whatever) to get a _somewhat spliney_ set of lines, and interpolate the real data linearly, reading this data. This isn't perfect, but I guess it's much more realistic. Plus, if the intervals are well chosen, it won't even look wrong.

Comment: well I have it so z-coord maps as distance along the spline. I think it's possible to encode a way to find which 'segment' a given z refers to, and then it's easy. Either way, the reason to do this in a shader is because _surely_ that's better than manually changing vertices in the CPU.